# Getting user country Facebook API PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently having a few issues accessing the country from a given user on facebook. I have requested the user_location permission and my graph API call also requests location however I am only ever returned the city and an ID for the location - never an actual country.

My requests etc are below. I am using the standard PHP SDK docs

```
// graph api request for user data
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=birthday,name,statuses,photos,location' );
$response = $request->execute();

// get response
$response = $response->getGraphObject();



 $data_we_need = array();

  $data_we_need['name'] = $response->getProperty('name');
  $data_we_need['birthday'] = $response->getProperty('birthday');
  $data_we_need['location'] = $response->getProperty('location');


  $statuses = $response->getProperty('statuses');
  $data_we_need['statuses'] = $statuses->asArray();

  $photos = $response->getProperty('photos');
  $data_we_need['photos'] = $photos->asArray();
```

I am returned an results like:

```
  [name] => xxxxxx
    [birthday] => 05/14/1990
    [location] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
        (
            [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Facebook\GraphObject
            [backingData:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 112087812151796
                    [name] => Gloucester, Gloucestershire
                )

        )
```

I need to be able to get country from the location data provided.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the location & hometown fields are user inputs (community pages), hence you won't get stable results using the facebook API. You might rather want to try detecting the country yourself with the IP.

Comment: hmm I was aware users input this info themselves but was happy to take this info as correct. If no solution is to be found I will use your IP suggestion :) thanks